# Как в оплате работает url оповещения?

Tags: php

Подключаю оплату на сайт. Сразу после успешной оплаты клиента кидает на сайт, где я проверяю код транзакции и делаю все необходимое. Но если он оплатил, где ему выставили счет на оплату, редиректа не мой сайт не будет, он оплатит счет и все. Как мне проверять что он оплатил?

Comment: На счету — если пришли деньги значит оплатил.

Comment: проверять факт платежа по сранице, куда клиента отправляет после оплаты - в корне не верно! не делайте так! проверьте, скорее всего подключенная вами платежная система умеет сама сообщать о результате оплаты на указанный вами url. Запросом бекенд-бекенд, без участия клиента.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын напишите нормальный ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 4):

Первым делом, хочу предостеречь: не реализуйте подтверждение оплаты в коде страницы, куда клиента отправляет платежная система (далее ПС) после оплаты. Это грозит серьезными проблемами с оплатой, которые проявятся, скорее всего, только при реальном потоке клиентов.

(отступление: *наша команда совсем недавно сталкивалась с подобной проблемой у одного из крупных постоянных клиентов. с завидной регулярностью не фиксировались платежи покупателей через PayPal. это продолжалось около полугода. наконец выяснилось, что программист, реализовавший подключение ПС, "немного" схалтурил и проводил подтверждение платежей именно таким, неправильным способом*).

Дело в том, что возврат клиента на ожидаемую вами страницу совершенно не гарантирован: может прерваться интернет соединение, клиент просто закроет вкладку или еще масса вариантов. Это приведет к тому, что клиент заплатил деньги, а оплата у вас на сайте не была зафиксирована и товар ему не был предоставлен. Кроме этого, есть много вопросов с безопасностью такого запроса, которые нужно понимать и проконтролировать при реализации.

Вместо этого, большинство ПС (по моему опыту: из, примерно, десятка российских и зарубежных ПС ни одна не лишена этого функционала) умеет сообщать вам о результате операции на указанные вами в настройках адреса. В зависимости от используемой ПС, эти настройки могу быть у вас в личном кабинете или устанавливаться исключительно через обращение в тех. поддержку; может использоваться как один адрес, для успешных и "фейловых" операций, так и 2-3 разных адреса.

К примеру, [на странице документации robokassa](http://docs.robokassa.ru/#1160) я нашел [описание настроек магазина](https://goo.gl/LwjU6X), где есть поле **Result URL**. Так же, здесь можно выбрать метод, которым будет отправлен запрос (GET|POST). Здесь же, на соседних страницах, подробно описан этот запрос и его параметры.

Такая же картина (с достаточно подробным описанием всего этого функционала) наблюдается у всех крупных ПС. У более мелких, зачастую, эту информацию присылают менеджеры в процессе подключения. Они же могут запросить у вас все необходимые адреса.

От вас требуется реализовать, по заданному адресу, скрипт, который будет принимать запрос от ПС, обрабатывать параметры и фиксировать/фейлить операцию оплаты. Среди параметров, у любой ПС, обязательно присутствует некий signatureKey (разумеется, название может быть любым), который представляет собой хитрый хеш. В документации ПС должно быть указано, как и из чего генерится этот хеш, а вы, при поступлении запроса, должны эту "подпись запроса" проверять на корректность. Этим обеспечивается отсутствие возможности поддельного запроса.

Если вы захотите услышать какую-либо конкретику или у вас появятся дополнительные вопросы - прошу вас, укажите, о какой ПС идет речь.

Comment: Иван, а если ввиду неопредолимых факторов ответ от ПС на Result URL не придет? ПС будет добиваться подтверждения прихода или как?